# JQuery Mobile list not getting correct style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have an unordered list in my html file

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="mylist" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a" >

</ul>
```

The list elements are populated from the database in the js file

```
$('#mylist').append('<li><a href="#"> <h1 class="myHeader">'+item.name+'</h1><p class="myParagraph">'+item.state+'<br>'+item.zipcode+'</p></a></li>');
```

This is what I do in the style sheet

```
.myHeader.ui-li-heading {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

.myParagraph.ui-li-desc {
    color: #333;
    overflow: show;
    text-overflow: clip;
    white-space: normal;
    height: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

The problem is that the list is not getting the correct style. Am I doing it completely wrong? What could be a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing:

```
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

Here's an example made from your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Z6wzQ/

More information can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html. Look at a heading **Updating lists**.